# Jquery - For Conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following function, how can I include an else statement once the for statement is no longer true?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".current").text("1");
        $("#NextPage").click(function () {
            var a = parseInt($(".current").text());
            var b = parseInt($(".total").text());
            if (a <= b){
                for (var i = 0; i <= b; i++) {
                    $(".current").text(i);
                }
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: `else` only works with `if`, not `for`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, it looks like you removed your `for (` in that latest edit.

Comment: I realize that, but once my i is no longer less than b, I want to trigger another function.

Comment: This is a pagination demo. Pretty much once the current page is = to the total pages, I need to start disabling some things.

Comment: Then just put code below the `for`'s body (the `{ }`), and that code will execute once the loop is done (and the loop is done when its condition becomes `false`).

Comment: Put that as an answe I'll award it to you.... thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` keyword isn't paired with `for`, only with `if`. If you want to execute code once the loop is done, simply put code below the `for` loop's body, and that code will execute when the loop finished. Loops finish when their conditions are `false`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= b; i++) {
    // for loop body code
}
// put code here to execute immediately after the loop finishes
```

Comment: SO is making me wait 7 minutes, ill come back shortly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
  <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".current").text("1");
            $("#NextPage").click(function () {
                var a = parseInt($(".current").text());
                var b = parseInt($(".total").text());
                if (a <= b){
                    for (var i = 0; i <= b; i++) {
                        $(".current").text(i);
                          if (a >= b){
                          break;             
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
         });
    </script>
```